# Need help bringing in data from other worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data in  three worksheets titled Expenses, Summary Fees and Hours. I'm trying to use a formula to bring in the data from the Expenses worksheet and fill it into the cells of the Summary Fees worksheet based on type of Expense and Date. But I keep on getting #VALUE and it says it's because of a wrong data type.

This is the formula:

=SUMIFS(Expenses!$E$6:$E$2505,Expenses!$C$6:$C$2505,'Summary - Fees'!$A31,Hours!$B$14:$B$2511,'Summary - Fees'!I$28)

Expenses!$E$6:$E$2505: Amount of each expense

Expenses!$C$6:$C$2505: Type of each expense

'Summary - Fees'!$A31: Type of each expense(In the spreadsheet I'm trying to bring data in)

Hours!$B$14:$B$2511: Dates of each expense

'Summary - Fees'!I$28: Date of each expense(In the spreadsheet I'm trying to bring data in)

Thanks!

Comment: Try it with `Hours!$B$14:$B$2513` . In a [SUMIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIFS-function-9DD6179E-CCED-41DD-AC38-08FDF5B929E5) the sum and criteria ranges have to be the same *size* although they do not have to be the same rows.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from a Comment from [@Jeeped](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4039065/jeeped):

> Try it with Hours!$B$14:$B$2513 . In a SUMIFS function the sum and criteria ranges have to be the same size although they do not have to be the same rows.